# Flutter apps won't run after switching from WIN 10 to Ubuntu

Tags: android, flutter

App originally created in Win 10. I switched to Ubuntu.
When I try to run an app I get the following error.
Any ideas where do I need to edit the path (prev. C:\)?

Thanks, Ron

```
* What went wrong:                                                      
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:flutterBuildDebug'.  
> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\\Dev\\FlutterApps\\xxxxxxxxx\\lib\\main.dart
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, flutter saves the path of your packages in a file. So, the error you are getting is because the path from Windows file system are saved in your project and those path are not valid on Ubuntu. To solve this:

1. open terminal in your project directory and use `flutter clean`.
2. then `flutter packages get`
3. now try to run your app.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I just ran `flutter clean` which removed the build folder. Then ran `flutter run` and it rebuilt the build folder and loads now.